# Error while linking a class in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an Objective C program to log and I am using Ubuntu to compile it.

While compiling, I am getting error as

```
 /tmp/ccJKC2MN.o:(.data+0x150): undefined reference to
 `__objc_class_name_AbcLogger'
```

I have linked all my header files at the starting of each class.

My program:

```
Logger.h
Logger.m
AbcLogger.h
AbcLogger.m
example.m
```

To compile it I am using the command:

```
gcc  -x objective-c -I/usr/include/GNUstep    \
     -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString \
     -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS                \
     Logger.h AbcLogger.h example.m -lgnustep-base -o human
```

Can you please help me with the issue. Ask for the code if you need it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be including `Logger.m` and `AbcLogger.m` in the `gcc` command? The snippet posted is referencing the .h files.

Comment: I tried to add that too but still it is not working. I searched in google and tried to compile it with a different command using "gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgnustep-base Logger.h Logger.m AbcLogger.h AbcLogger.m example.m -o new" but it is also returning error as "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fobjc-nonfragile-abi’".Can you guys help me out with this. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make a GNUmakefile

I can't say if this is 100% accurate because I can't be sure of this program setup, but I would write one like this:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME=human
human_OBJC_FILES=\
Logger.m\
AbcLogger.m\
example.m

human_HEADERS=\
Logger.h\
AbcLogger.h

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

you will need GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES to lead to the GNUstep/Makefiles path so if it spits out an error like "Can't find common.make" make sure you run

```
export GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/(Where ever you GNUstep folder is)/Makefiles
```

just type

```
make
```

GOOD LUCK!